# How to fix Android resource linking failed dialogCornerRadius not found

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

I'm developing an app where I have this issue.

Android gradle/caches/transforms

> Android resource linking failed
>   */appcompat-1.0.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

I've readed that this issue can be solved  API 27 to 28.
The problem I have is that if I update to 28 I lose the sense of my app, because all my app is made by Fragments and in the last version of Android Studio api the fragments are deprecated.

```
       v28/values-v28.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
          <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
          <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
          <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
            <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
            <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
          </style>
          <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
            <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
          </style>
</resources>
```

So, How can I run my app keeping the fragments (not updating to Android 9 api).

I want to modify item `dialogCornerRadius`

Answer (score 9):

> if I update to 28 I lose the sense of my app because all my app is made by Fragment

Nothing is lost.
[`android.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) is deprecated in API 28, but it doesn't mean that it doesn't work. Also you can:

- use [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment) in support library
- or better use [`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html) in androidx library

In any case

> /values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found

**requires** `compileSdkVersion 28`.

**You have these options:**

- use a support library v27 with `compileSdkVersion 27`
- use a support library v28 with `compileSdkVersion 28`
- [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) your project to **androidx** with `compileSdkVersion 29` or `compileSdkVersion 28`

Comment: Thank you, but when I update to compileSdkVersion to 28 or 29 I have these issues error: cannot find symbol class Fragment... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MauroStancato Check the package name of Fragment and import the right one (support or androidx). In any case android.app.Fragment still exists.

Comment: Thank you Gabriele I don't want to bother you but I have a last question... I have changed androidx.frament.app.Fragment but I have other libraries. These are the following: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

Comment: Do you have the name of those libraries in androidx? (FragmentActivity, FragmentManager, FragmentStatePagerAdapter, PagerAdapter, ViewPager)

Comment: Here the full mapping for [classes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) and [libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)